# BasedOn style not overriding styles Resources

Tags: wpf

**Edit:** The colour override works on some buttons I have got, which work the same way, except I don't define any colours in the main style resources, I just setup the Color tags but with no colour property

---

The following style has got 3 colours set to be the default colours used throughout the style, however I want to over ride these 3 colours if I wanted a different colour set on the button.

Here are the ComboBox's, first one should be default colour, second one should be Green override.

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" SelectedIndex="0" Text="Select USB Device">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Test 1" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Test 2" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Test 3" />
        </ComboBox>
        <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" SelectedIndex="0" Text="Select USB Device" Style="{StaticResource ComboBlue}">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Test 1" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Test 2" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Test 3" />
        </ComboBox>
```

**XAML, main style**

```
<!-- Combo Box Style -->
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="colour1" Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource NorGrey}, Path=Color}" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="colour2" Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource DarGrey}, Path=Color}" />
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="colour3" Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource LigGrey}, Path=Color}" />

            <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
                            <Border x:Name="Border"
                                    Padding="4"
                                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                    Background="Transparent">
                                <ContentPresenter />
                            </Border>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource colour3}" />
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>

            <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxToggleButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Border x:Name="Border"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            CornerRadius="5"
                            Background="{StaticResource colour1}"/>
                    <Border Grid.Column="0"
                            CornerRadius="5,0,0,5"
                            Margin="1"
                            Background="{StaticResource colour2}" />
                    <Path x:Name="Arrow"
                          Grid.Column="1"
                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"
                          Fill="White" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource colour3}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>

            <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboBoxTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
                <Border x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                        Focusable="False"
                        Background="{StaticResource colour1}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="20" />
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="80" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Grid>
                        <ToggleButton x:Name="ToggleButton"
                                      Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButton}"
                                      Grid.Column="2"
                                      Focusable="False"
                                      ClickMode="Press"
                                      IsChecked="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                                          IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItem}"
                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                                          ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding ItemTemplateSelector}"
                                          Margin="6,6,10,6"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                        <TextBox x:Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                                 Style="{x:Null}"
                                 Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBox}"
                                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                 Margin="3,3,23,3"
                                 Focusable="True"
                                 Background="Transparent"
                                 Visibility="Hidden"
                                 IsReadOnly="{TemplateBinding IsReadOnly}" />
                        <Popup x:Name="Popup"
                               Placement="Bottom"
                               IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                               AllowsTransparency="True"
                               Focusable="False"
                               PopupAnimation="Slide">
                            <Grid x:Name="DropDown"
                                  SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                  MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                                  MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                                <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                        Background="{StaticResource colour1}" />
                                <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6"
                                              SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True"
                                                KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Grid>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="AllowsTransparency" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4" />
                            <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And here are the styles which are used to override the colours, placed BELOW the main style. But for some reason the colours are not changing.

```
<!-- Combo Box Colors -->
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}" TargetType="ComboBox" x:Key="ComboGreen">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource NorGreen}, Path=Color}" x:Key="colour1" />
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource DarGreen}, Path=Color}" x:Key="colour2" />
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource LigGreen}, Path=Color}" x:Key="colour3" />
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}" TargetType="ComboBox" x:Key="ComboGrey">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource NorGrey}, Path=Color}" x:Key="colour1" />
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource DarGrey}, Path=Color}" x:Key="colour2" />
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource LigGrey}, Path=Color}" x:Key="colour3" />
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}" TargetType="ComboBox" x:Key="ComboBlue">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource NorBlue}, Path=Color}" x:Key="colour1" />
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource DarBlue}, Path=Color}" x:Key="colour2" />
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource LigBlue}, Path=Color}" x:Key="colour3" />
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
    <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}" TargetType="ComboBox" x:Key="ComboRed">
        <Style.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource NorRed}, Path=Color}" x:Key="colour1" />
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource DarRed}, Path=Color}" x:Key="colour2" />
            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding Source={StaticResource LigRed}, Path=Color}" x:Key="colour3" />
        </Style.Resources>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find the solution, I used the wrong resource type. When referencing the colours I should of used `DynamicResource` not `StaticResource`.